# How by changing ciphertext can the attacker know the length of the padding in POODLE attack

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, tls, attack, openssl

I try to understand the POODLE attack. I read that the attacker try to change one byte of the last block of the ciphertext. Becasue the last block is only have padding and the last byte is the padding length the attacker need that only the last byte remain the same. I understand how the attacker know if it stay the same I dont understand how the attacker know the value of the padding length.
I also dont understand why one in every 256 changes will be accepted.

Comment: See anatomy https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/what-is-poodle-attack/

Comment: From _https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf_; 
As the padding hides the exact size of the payload, the cookies’ size is not immediately
apparent, but inducing requests GET /, GET /A, GET /AA, ... allows the attacker to
observe at which point the block boundary gets crossed: after at most 16 such requests,
this will reveal the padding size, and thus the size of the cookies